# How to test ICMP in my stack over TAP device?

Tags: c, ubuntu, tcp, ping, tun-tap

I'm writting code to implement a simple TCP/IP stack over TAP device. But when I want to test ICMP code, I find that `ping $(TAP IP)` won't send packets to TAP device. It always sends them  to loopback. So how can I test my ICMP code?

My system is Ubuntu-18.04
When I test ARP, I use `arping -I $(TAP NAME) $(TAP IP)`, and it works fine.
But `ping -I $(TAP NAME) $(TAP IP)` still sends packets to loopback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to send out packet by your tap interface, you should set dst ip to remote addr instead of your local addr. Assume your tap ip is `192.168.1.10/24` , you should ping `192.168.1.20` for example. And before you ping, you should set static arp first.

```
arp -s 192.168.1.20 12:34:56:78:90:ab
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But what I mean is that I want to receive ping packets from tap to test my ICMP receive/reply function instead of sending out packets by tap interface. Your advice is still helpful, it helps me find some bugs in my ip layer.

Comment: APP <->tap<->kernel. When you run ping command, the packet is sent out by kernel via tap interface, and your app will receive it. When your app write icmp packet to tap, the packet is sent out by your app and received by kernel.

Comment: Oh, I got it! I set the fake remote ip and its route in source file, and configure the arp as your advice, then my stack can reply to the `ping`. Thank you so much! LOL